# It is vital for schools to respect the wishes of parents

Tags: sentence-construction

> It is vital for schools to respect the wishes of parents.

Can I rewrite the sentence to "To respect the wishes of parents is vital for schools."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but don't.  There is a reason for the cleft sentence construction: it moves the long and "heavy" infinitive clause to the end, where it belongs, rather than the start when it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! This seems like a passive-active sentence construction to me.

> In a sentence written in the active voice, the subject of sentence performs the action. In a sentence written in the passive voice, the subject receives the action.
> [Source](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/style/ccs_activevoice/)